# Where to put code on web server to load upon loading web page?

Tags: apache, http

I'm putting together my first web page, and I've been looking at these FTP files for the longest time and can't figure out where to put my code to make it load upon loading the webpage.

Currently, when accessing the web page, it loads a public_html folder, and then acts as an index where I can click on the php file to open (and access the html and whatnot.)

I don't want to look at the index though; I want it to load the code immediately. Where do I put it to do this? (and yes I've looked all over, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to do it.)

Comment: Have you tried naming your file `index.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web servers have a preferential list of 'target' webpages that it goes to when you go to a directory without specifying a file.

If you've got PHP scripts, you'll be naming your main file `index.php`. If you have HTML, then `index.htm` or `index.html` will be the desired ones. These will work on pretty much all servers. Which of the 3 files takes priority is usually up to the configuration of the server, but it'll most often be the `.php` one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a file to load as your home page so that it loads when you enter `yourdomain.com` in the browser or as the default file for a directory (`yourdomain.com/dir/`), the file should be named one of the following:

```
index.<ext>
Index.<ext>
default.<ext>
home.<ext>
```

Replace `<ext>` with the file extension. This list varies from server to server, but almost all servers will recognize `index.<ext>`.